# Mutating Vuex state in a mutation throws "Do not mutate Vuex store state outside mutation"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, quasar-framework

It's kinda strange to me, but it throws the error when mutating a vuex state OUTSIDE a mutation but its throwing when mutating INSIDE a mutation...

I'm trying to modify an object "form" that has a field "Table" (implemented with Quasar DataTable) and just throws when modifying rows (adding and remove one, for example). This object is the one that i'm using to display data in the table.

My actual flow is like this:
HTML Table button “ADD” with @click:“addNewRow(id)” -> vue method that dispatches Vuex’s action insertNewRow(id) -> Action insertNewRow commits a mutation “addNewRow(id)” -> Mutation addNewRow(id) finds the field in the object Form and adds a new row -> Vue warn…

EDIT: https://codesandbox.io/s/mzq48mlq4x working code.... surprise for me that this is working as intended, but the same code is throwing error outside codesandbox...

Comment: Please provide the code for the respective action and mutation.

Comment: EDITED: Add Action and Mutation code

Comment: Could you please make a snippet?

Comment: @deathangel908 I'm not sure how to make it with Quasar Framework, but I'll try

Comment: use https://codesandbox.io/s/vue

Comment: I have to guess, since I don't understand entirely what kind of objects your state is holding. Maybe tableToAdd is losing its state-context when you do the _.find.

So, what you might want to try is doing an index find and reference tableToAdd via its index in the array.

And then eventuall you do state.instanceItem.Childs[index].push(newRow)


BTW you might want to rename Childs to Children as this is the grammatically correct plural.

Comment: @LongHike changed to findIndex, but still not working... I'm trying to make a codesnippet with my actual code, so I guess it will be better

Comment: @deathangel908 https://codesandbox.io/s/mzq48mlq4x

Comment: If codesandbox works ok, could you post minimal example on github and share it?

Comment: @deathangel908 rewriting the code to upload to github in another project just works as intended with copy/paste the code needed....

Comment: This means issue is somewhere else in your original project